# set_yticklabels() does not remove the old tick labels

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have some code that generates in the same way three plots. The two first look fine, while the second has two different sets of y tick labels. The code to generate it is

```
for i, data in enumerate([pklin, psm, olin]):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    x, y = data[0], data[1]
    ax.set_xlabel(r'$\log_{10}k [h $Mpc$^{-1}] $', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax.set_xticks((0.05, 1e-1, 0.45))
    ax.set_xticklabels((0.05, 1e-1, 0.45), fontsize=fontsize)
    logx = np.log10(x)
    logy = np.log10(y)
    xticks = np.logspace(min(logx), max(logx), 4, base=10)
    yticks = np.logspace(min(logy), max(logy), 4, base=10)

    if i==0:
        yticks = [int(x) for x in np.round(yticks, -2)]
        ylabel = r'$\log_{10} P(k) [$Mpc$^3 h^{-3}]$'
        name  = 'Pklin'
        print('First plot done!')
    elif i==1:
        yticks = [int(x) for x in np.round(yticks, -2)]
        ylabel = r'$\log_{10} P_{smooth}(k) [$Mpc$^3 h^{-3}]$'
        name = 'Psm'
        print('Second plot done!')
    elif i==2:
        yticks = [x for x in np.round(yticks, 3)]
        ylabel = r'$\log_{10} O_{lin}(k)$'
        name = 'Olin'
        print('Third plot done!')

    ax.set_xticks(xticks)
    ax.set_xticklabels(np.round(xticks, 2), fontsize=fontsize)

    ax.set_yticks(yticks)
    ax.set_yticklabels(yticks, fontsize=fontsize)

    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel, fontsize=fontsize)
    plt.savefig(f'../figs/{name}.pdf')
```

[Image corresponding to `i=0`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5elrG.png)
[Image corresponding to `i=1`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G6A0.png)
[Image corresponding to `i=2`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmedw.png)

What I expected to see in the third image was the ytick labels as in the first two images, and I do not even know what to try.

Comment: You seem to be setting log scale on the y-axis (e.g. via `ax.set_yscale('log')`), but that code isn't shown.  (Also code to draw a plot is missing.) With a log scale, matplotlib makes both "major" and "minor" ticks. You could remove the minor ticks, e.g. via `ax.set_yticks([], minor=True)`.

Comment: This is true. Do you need the whole code to be replicated? I just wanted to add an excerpt of the code that produces these images and I forgot to add the log scale. However, it looks as if I did not communicate my question correctly. I meant that I do not want the ticklabels (this is the numbers that go with each tick) to be shown twice.

Comment: The whole code isn't needed, only the part that fully reproduces the problem.  The log scale is very important.  Instead of the real data, you can just plot some dummy data, e.g. a line from the bottom left to the top right using the min/max of the current curve. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76172924/edit) your post and fill in missing code and test data.  Preferrably you also add `import`s to make the code easily reproducible.

Comment: Okay so apparently the problem was that I thought that the previous ticklabels would get overwritten, but they did not. The problem is solved :)

Comment: The previous tick labels do get overwritten. But by default only the major ticks while the minor ticks stay unchanged.